# Группа администраторов в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Какая группа отвечает за группу администраторов в Ubuntu?
В файле `/etc/group` есть группа "adm" и есть группа "sudo". Так вот, если назначить пользователя администратором, то этот пользователь добавится к группе "adm" и "sudo". Но если убрать права администратора у этого пользователя и сделать его обычным, то он удалится только из группы "sudo", но останется в группе "adm". Непонятно какая группа за что отвечает.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Группа `adm` отвечает за доступ к некоторым логам в `/var/log`:

```
# посмотрим на типичный лог файл
ls -la /var/log/dmesg
# ответ:
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 58692 марта 17 12:24 /var/log/dmesg
# посмотрим группы сислога:
groups syslog
# ответ:
syslog : syslog adm
```

Группа `sudo` разрешает запускать с правами суперпользователя - это механизм, чтобы [не работать под рутом](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B2_ubuntu). sudo можно настроить:

```
sudo cat /etc/sudoers
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Таким образом, в `sudo` прописано, что `root`, и пользователи групп `admin` и `sudo` имеют супер привилегии. Группа `admin` появилась  исторически, и оставлена для обратной совместимости. У меня на 14 убунте группы нет, но в `sudoers` она упоминается.

Для редактирования этого файла нужно ввести `sudo visudo`

## Какая группа отвечает за группу администраторов?

При установке системы с нуля "админы" - это те, кто входит в `sudo`. А затем - как настроите.

### Подробности

Нет понятия "система отличает админа от обычного юзера". Система более гибкая, все правила изложены в файле `sudoers`.

Суперадмин `root` по-умолчанию в Убунте отключен. При установке создается пользователь, который включен в группу `sudo`, и через `sudo {команда}` может выполнять любые административные задачи.

Но затем sudo можно настроить так, что любой пользователь сможет выполнять любые, даже административные действия. И даже снести систему. И для этого не нужно включать пользователя в какую-то группу, достаточно "как надо" настроить файл `sudoers`.

Пример. Мне нужно перезагружать Sphinx из веб-интерфейса, но я не хочу давать абсолютно все права веб-серверу (это не безопасно). Через `sudoers` я могу это сделать.

### Резюме

Сначала следует проанализировать файл `sudoers`, понять как распределены роли, и тогда придет понимаение "кто тут админ".

Также выполните

```
awk -F: '($3 == "0") {print}' /etc/passwd
```

должна быть только 1 учетная запись с UID = 0, это root

Comment: так а какая в итоге группа отвечает за группу администраторов?
по какой группе система отличает админа от обычного юзера?
по членству в группе sudo?

Comment: или если по другому спросить: какая группа является той самой " исторически появившейся admin"?

Comment: добавил ответ "Какая группа отвечает за группу администраторов?"

Answer (score 2):

Считайте что группа администраторов - это группа `sudo`
Однако в Linux, путем модифицирования `/etc/sudoers` можно сделать любого пользователя администратором, либо любую группу администраторами.

По сути не важно какая группа является админской, важно только - какая группа (или пользователь) имеет возможность работать с root правами.