# Linux группы и их возможности

Tags: linux

Если открыть файл `/etc/group`, то можно увидеть ряд различных групп. Стало интересно, что может пользователь, который входит в ту или иную группу? Какие права он приобретает? Например, мой пользователь входит в группы `wheel`, `lp`, `power`, `network`. Как посмотреть что дает данная группа пользователю, какие права и т.д? Я пытался таким образом: `man wheel`, но безрезультатно. Понятное дело что я мог бы написать в `google` мол `manjaro wheel group` и слоняться по форумам. Но может быть в Linux есть какая-то утилита или что-то в этом роде, чтобы узнать информацию о той или иной группе?

Comment: Группы создаются и удаляются, в системе может не быть указанных групп.  Права на любую группу можно навесить любые, все зависит от файла `/etc/sudoers`. Вот мой ответ, который частично прояснит ситуацию https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/800756/%d0%93%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-ubuntu/800776#800776

Comment: Есть команды, _ls_, _find_, _fuser_, _lsof_, _getent_, и ещё миллион других, которые в целом дают некое понимание, что и куда.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что такого инструмента в Linux нет.
Назначение групп описаны в документации к Linux или в описании к программам, которые создают свои группы при установке.

**Список стандартных групп:**

- daemon - от имени этой группы и пользователя daemon запускаютcя сервисы, которым необходима возможность записи файлов на диск.
- sys - группа открывает доступ к исходникам ядра и файлам include сохраненным в системе
- sync - позволяет выполнять команду /bin/sync
- games - разрешает играм записывать свои файлы настроек и историю в определенную папку
- man - позволяет добавлять страницы в директорию /var/cache/man
- lp - позволяет использовать устройства параллельных портов
- mail - позволяет записывать данные в почтовые ящики /var/mail/
- proxy - используется прокси серверами, нет доступа записи файлов на диск
- www-data - с этой группой запускается веб-сервер, она дает доступ на запись /var/www, где находятся файлы веб-документов
- list - позволяет просматривать сообщения в /var/mail
- nogroup - используется для процессов, которые не могут создавать файлов на жестком диске, а только читать, обычно применяется вместе с пользователем nobody.
- adm - позволяет читать логи из директории /var/log
- tty - все устройства /dev/vca разрешают доступ на чтение и запись пользователям из этой группы
- disk - открывает доступ к жестким дискам /dev/sd* /dev/hd*, можно сказать, что это аналог рут доступа.
- dialout - полный доступ к серийному порту
- cdrom - доступ к CD-ROM
- wheel - позволяет запускать утилиту sudo для повышения привилегий
- audio - управление аудиодрайвером
- src - полный доступ к исходникам в каталоге /usr/src/
- shadow - разрешает чтение файла /etc/shadow
- utmp - разрешает запись в файлы /var/log/utmp /var/log/wtmp
- video - позволяет работать с видеодрайвером
- plugdev - позволяет монтировать внешние устройства USB, CD и т д
- staff - разрешает запись в папку /usr/local

Comment: _wheel_ используется не только для _sudo_.

Answer (score 0):

Группы создаются пользователем, и сами по себе ни чего не означают, права для группы можно посмотреть в /etc/sudoers